Derivation of a spin connection in general relativity
On my journey to understand the mathematical structure behind general relativity, I came across the concept of a spin connection. which (I understand) is a connection defined in a spinor bundle.
The problem is that the Wikipedia article on spin connections just states that:
1- It comes from lifting an affine connection/Levi-Civita connection on spacetime.
2 - Then after saying this, it just throws at you the components of (what I deduce is) the connection 1-form
$ \omega_{\mu}^{ab} = e_{\nu}^a \Gamma^{\nu}_{\sigma \mu} e^{\sigma b} + e^a_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}e^{\nu b} $
Without stating where it comes from in an explicit form.
Is there any detailed derivation of these? How would you derive this connection from the Levi-Civita/affine connection?

For a fully rigorous derivation one must go through spinor bundle construction and find the local formula for the induced spin connection that way, but here's a rough "derivation" for this local formula. The spin connection induces a covariant derivative on tensors with components $T^a_\nu$ in the following way
$$D_\mu T^a_\nu=\partial_\mu T^a_\nu-{\Gamma^\rho}_{\mu\nu}T^a_\rho+{{\omega_\mu}^a}_b T^b_\nu. $$
Recall that our local frame $e_a=e_a^\mu\partial_\mu$, has dual forms $e^b=e^b_\nu dx^\nu$, such that $e^a(e_b)=\delta^a_b=e_a^\mu e^b_\mu$ and $g(e_a,e_b)=\eta_{ab}=g_{\mu\nu}e_a^\mu e_b^\nu$. With this in mind, for the spin connection to be compatible with the Levi-Civita connection we require that the local frame must be parallel
$$D_\mu e_\nu^a=\partial_\mu e_\nu^a - {\Gamma^\rho}_{\mu\nu} e_\rho^a + {{{\omega}_\mu}^a}_b e_\nu^b=0, $$
contracting this equation with $e^\nu_c$ we obtain
$$\begin{align}e^\nu_c\partial_\mu e_\nu^a-e^\nu_c{\Gamma^\rho}_{\mu\nu}e_\rho^a+ {{{\omega}_\mu}^a}_b e_\nu^b e_c^\nu &=0\\
e^\nu_c\partial_\mu e_\nu^a-e^\nu_c{\Gamma^\rho}_{\mu\nu}e_\rho^a+ {{{\omega}_\mu}^a}_c&=0.\end{align}$$
Solving for the components of the spin connection we have
$${{{\omega}_\mu}^a}_c=e_\rho^a{\Gamma^\rho}_{\mu\nu}e^\nu_c-e^\nu_c\partial_\mu e_\nu^a.$$
Finally we are free to raise the last index with $\eta^{bc}$
$${{\omega}_\mu}^{ab}=e_\rho^a{\Gamma^\rho}_{\mu\nu}e^{\nu b}-e^{\nu b}\partial_\mu e_\nu^a.$$
The formula you stated is of course equivalent by noting that $\partial_\mu( e^{\nu b}e^a_\nu)=e^{\nu b}\partial_\mu e_\nu^a+e_\nu^a\partial_\mu e^{\nu b}=0$ since $e^{\nu b}e^a_\nu =\eta^{ab}$.
